firefox use application.ini without command line param
Is there a way to set/change a default application.ini that is used without the -app parameter?
The problem is that if Firefox (started with this parameter) is made the default browser then the systems default browser setting does not include this parameter. So on clicking some link in other apps or clicking a html file, then the browser is invoked without that -app parameter. And this may leads to using different profiles (depending on the changes in the application.ini)

Your second sentence doesn't make a lot of sense. Could you spend a bit of time explaining this more please?

@music2myear  I tried
